# Combining jQuery Validate and ajax form submission

Tags: javascript, validation, jquery

I have a simple form like

```
<form id="invite_form">

    <input type="text" name="invite_email" id="invite_email" />

    <textarea name="invite_message">Hello!</textarea>

    <div id="send_div">
         <span id="send_btn">Send</span> 
    </div>
</form>
```

My JS is as follows to submit the form via Ajax:

```
$('#send_btn').live('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var form = $('#invite_form');

    $.ajax({
        url: '/invite',
        type: "POST",
        data: form.serialize(),
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(html) {
            $('#send_div').html('Success!');
        }
    });
});
```

This works fine.

Now I would like to wrap a jQuery Validate function around this code to make sure [1] the email field is filled and [2] is valid email.

I am using Jorn's bassistance.de jQuery validation plugin from http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/.

Can anyone give a roadmap of how to tie the validation call to this ajax?

Thanks for helping, much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#send_btn').live('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var form = $('#invite_form');
    if(form.valid()) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/invite',
            type: "POST",
            data: form.serialize(),
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(html) {
                $('#send_div').html('Success!');
            }
        });
    else {
     ;   //do whatever if the form is not valid
    }
});
```